# Wrong argument: why is a List<List<>> not equivalent to a List<Object>?

Tags: java

This following code gives me a compilation error:

```java
public static Function<int[], Stream<Tuple2<Formatter, List<Object>>>> acquisitionColors = (col) -> Seq.of(
            Tuple.tuple(Formatter.COLOR,
                    Seq.of(
                            Seq.of(col).toList(),
                            Seq.of(
                                    Seq.of("Stop", "Stoq", null, "red").toList(),
                                    Seq.of("Learning", "Learninh", null, "gray").toList(),
                                    Seq.of("Stop", "Stoq", null, "red").toList(),
                                    Seq.of("Reduce", "Reducf", null, "orange").toList(),
                                    Seq.of("Keep", "Keeq", null, "green").toList(),
                                    Seq.of("Increase", "Increasf", null, "blue").toList()
                            ).toList()
                    ).toList()
            )
    );
```

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Object>>', required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>' 
Inspection info:  
tuple (Formatter,java.uti.List<java.lang.Object>) in Tuple cannot be applied 
to (Formatter,java.util.List<java.util.List<? extends java.lanq.Object>>)
```

However, if I wrap that list with a `Collections.singletonList`, it works:

```
public static Function<int[], Stream<Tuple2<Formatter, List<Object>>>> acquisitionColors = (col) -> Seq.of(
            Tuple.tuple(Formatter.COLOR,
                    Collections.singletonList(
                     ...
                    ).toList())
            )
    );
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts of an answer:
`List<Object>` is invariant, thus expression typed as `List<List<? extends java.lanq.Object>>` cannot be assigned to `List<Object>`
Google for variance in Java, for example:
[DZone article on variance in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/variance-in-java)

`public static <T> List<T> singletonList(T o)` is a generic method. For generic methods type inference is applied. In your context, T is expected to be an Object, and `List<List<? extends java.lanq.Object>>` can be cast to an Object. 
See [What is type argument inference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20argument%20inference%20in%20general?)

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I cast a `List<List<Object>>` to `List<Object>`? isn't `List<Object>` an `Object` too?

Because [Java Generics are not implicitly polymorphic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/5106170). `List<Object>` means it can have any `Object` in the given list, even a `Map<?, ?>`, but when you cast it to a `List<List>`, It no longer makes sense to be containing any `Object` and is limited to only `List`

> How does it work when use `Collections.singletonList()` ?

Simply because `Collections.singletonList()` is returning a `List<T>` [as per the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) so the compiler won't be complaining about it during runtime. See Lesiak's answer about Type Argument Inference during compile time.

Comment: `Collections.singletonList() is infact returning a List<Object> as per the docs.` I believe you are misinterpreting the docs.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look to type erasure and raw type in Java.

Lists use generics so when your try to create a list with defining raw type it uses `Object`

```
List list;
// means that list holds Objects

List<String> listOfStrings;
// means that list holds Strings
```

Now for the case of `List<List>`

List is an `interface` which has no suitable casting as an `Object` there for when evaluating this statement the JVM notice that you are try to use items that are neither Objects or 'children of it'

```
List<List<? extends java.lanq.Object>> // (Object or children of it)
```

Comment: This is completely untrue.  Every implementation of `List` is a subtype of `Object`.